# ResolutionFailure error while installing Twilio again with other dependencies in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, twilio, twilio-api, pyjwt

I need to install twilio in my django-project. The project already has a Pipfile and pipfile.lock containing the other dependencies needed. When I try to install twilio using the command "pipenv install twilio" its gives a resolutionfailure error. The issue is that twilio requires the PyJWT version to be 1.7.1 but other dependencies require the version of PyJWT to be greater than 2 and less than 3. How do I manage to maintain different versions of the PyJWT version and How do I install twilio with the same?

**The error is below:**

```
Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: Could not find a version that matches pyjwt<3,==1.7.1,>=2 (from twilio==6.62.1->-r C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenvjh75ft37requirements\pipenv-727q
x30b-constraints.txt (line 32))
Tried: 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.4, 0.1.5, 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.3, 0.2.3, 0.3.0, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.3.2, 0.4.0, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.
4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.4.3, 1.0.0, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.1.0, 1.3.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.2, 1.5.0, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.1, 1.5.
2, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.3, 1.6.0, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.1, 1.6.3, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.4, 1.7.0, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.0
Skipped pre-versions: 2.0.0a1, 2.0.0a1, 2.0.0a2, 2.0.0a2
There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies:
  pyjwt<3,>=2 (from djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.7.2->-r C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenvjh75ft37requirements\pipenv-727qx30b-constraints.txt (line 30
))
  pyjwt==1.7.1 (from twilio==6.62.1->-r C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenvjh75ft37requirements\pipenv-727qx30b-constraints.txt (line 32))
```

Comment: Hi, take a look at this issue https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/issues/556

Comment: Hi @Aprimus, I did have a look at that issue earlier. but I couldn't find a proper way to resolve the error